# Solution To create or update static pages in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

How can I create interface or solution to the website owner to be able to create or update static pages in Django without open source code, for example, a website owner needs to update text in aboutus page or want to create a new static page like new promotion details.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you want to allow user to update the text or add new page dynamically. If so you can go for Django content management system you can use django mezzanine. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-get-started-with-django-based-mezzanine-cms-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks Priyank, This is exactly what I am searching for, But I think I will use https://wagtail.readthedocs.io/en/v2.3/ because this one support Django2

Comment: @Eslamspot Please accept the answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I can't because I am less than 15 score.